# Unable to upload file in EC2 using PHP move_uploaded_file

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

I am trying to upload a zip file in EC2 suing PHP.

```
$count = 0;
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $i => $name) {
            if (strlen($_FILES['files']['name'][$i]) > 1) {
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i], $dirPath.strtolower($name))) {
                    $count++;
                }else{
                die ("not success no file sorry in move_upload" . $dirPath.strtolower($name) . "  ". $numFiles . " ".$count);
              }
            }else{
              die ("not success no file sorry in strlen" . $numFiles . " ".$count);
            }
        }
    }else{
      die ("not success no file sorry" . $numFiles . " ".$count);
    }
```

This code failed at **if (move_uploaded_file**, $_FILES is OK. but the problem is in *move_uploaded_file*.

my ps aux | grep apache  output is

```
apache   23762  0.0  3.1 570272 32488 ?        Sl   Mar29   0:14 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   26487  0.0  2.7 565912 27628 ?        Sl   Mar30   0:08 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   26488  0.0  3.3 572044 34396 ?        Sl   Mar30   0:08 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   27416  0.0  2.7 762324 28080 ?        Sl   Mar30   0:07 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   27838  0.0  2.5 563948 26104 ?        Sl   Mar30   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   27839  0.0  2.7 566384 28124 ?        Sl   Mar30   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   28124  0.0  2.3 560860 23472 ?        Sl   Mar30   0:05 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   28173  0.0  1.9 455504 20160 ?        Sl   Mar30   0:04 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   28175  0.0  1.9 455504 20168 ?        Sl   Mar30   0:04 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   28176  0.0  1.9 455504 20200 ?        Sl   Mar30   0:04 /usr/sbin/httpd
ec2-user 31044  0.0  0.2 110460  2192 pts/0    S+   01:47   0:00 grep --color=auto apache
```

I tried to **sudo chown -R ec2-user /var/www/html**  but stll upload fails.

Please help. The same PHP upload code works on other shared hosting providers. This php file is getting called by Jquery Ajax.

Comment: What is `$dirpath`? Do you have write permission there? Probably not. Try checking with `is_writable($dirpath);` before trying to write to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is $dirPath.strtolower($name).

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i], $dirPath.strtolower($name))) {
```

As I known, you you must write: strtolower($dirPath . $name)

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i], strtolower($dirPath . $name))) {
```

An in all other code, you must change this!

Answer (score 0):

Hello Everyone I did encountered this error lately, I am also a beginner and solved this problem in just 3 hours this is the thing that helps me. I use Linux AMI EC2 intance.

The problem might be all about the "Writeability"(sorry I am not really familiar with terms please bear with me) permission of the folder maybe it is only allowed for the root

First make a script on the live serve  and include this code to know what is the name 
of the client that will execute the move_uploaded_file command of php

```
<?php
echo exec('whoami');    
?>
```

Then it results to give me "apache" as my client's user
After it look for the folder the destination check if it is writeable by the client's side
using

ls -lh /var/www/folder/

then you will see like
the root and www on it
change it to

chown -R apache:apache /folder destination

Always take note that the user is the result of whoami php script

Hope this helps